# Reading all object files in directory with single stream

Tags: java, file, object, io, stream

If I had a directory filled with different object files, is there a way I could input them into my application without opening a new stream every time? I am currently using `ObjectInputStream`, but I don't mind using another form of IO.

For example, if I stored my users directly onto my harddrive as objects (each having their own file: *name.user*), is there a way I could load them all back in using the same stream? Or would it be impossible seeing how a new `File` object would be needed for each individual file? Is there a way around this?

Comment: What's an "object file" (considering you're open to not using ObjectInputStream)

Comment: @aioobe A serialized object in the form of a file on my harddrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file will need its own stream behind the scenes; there's no way round that. But that doesn't stop you creating your own `InputStream` that manages this for you, and then allows you to read everything off from one stream.

The idea would be that when you try to read from your `CompoundObjectInputStream` or whatever, it looks to see if there are any more files that it hasn't yet processed, and opens one if so using another stream, and passes the data through. When it reaches the point where there are no more files in that directory, the `CompoundObjectInputStream` indicates end-of-stream.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, although I was hoping there would be a way to only need one stream for this. I guess I'ma have to stick with a "master" stream for now.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Each physical file requires its own `FileInputStream`, `FileChannel`, or other corresponding `native` accessor.

Note that `File` has no direct link to a physical file, it is just an abstract path name.